# Only half of the object is shiny

Tags: materials

[image]

Hey, so this is my problem. I want to have the whole object bumpy and shiny like the right part, however only 2 sides are like this, the front and the end is mat. They have the same material, in UV map I smart projected it, they are the same size and position there, still getting this result

Comment: pls provide material nodes and/or blend file

Comment: @Chris here you go: [link] https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YdopXvHC9v_oOtBLlnl6q6DAtWZdi8b2?usp=sharing [/link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just apply the scale of your house, then you will get:

[image]

Hint: maybe you should adjust your uv map a bit so that it looks better ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yup, I was not done with that :P